# how to speed up and optimize mysql search with indexes

Tags: mysql, php

I need to optimize performance on a search with lots of strings like `Z1719121`.

my table structure:

```
codfabrica  => varchar 191 => nullable
codoriginal => varchar 191 => nullable
aplicacao   => mediumText  => nullable
```

table indexes:

```
codfabrica  => non_unique 1 | seq_in_index 1 | collation A    | cardinality 42466
codoriginal => non_unique 1 | seq_in_index 1 | collation A    | cardinality 7449
aplicacao   => non_unique 1 | seq_in_index 1 | collation NULL | cardinality 42550
```

laravel query code:

```
$allKeys = [...]; // array with lots of strings
$q = MyModel::query();
$q->whereIn('codfabrica', $allKeys);
$q->orWhereIn('codoriginal', $allKeys);
$q->orWhereRaw('MATCH (aplicacao) AGAINST (?)', array($allKeys));
```

results:

```
array with 1000 strings => took 5 seconds
array with 2500 strings => took 35 seconds
```

Is there any way I can optimize this search?

I am not experienced with INDEX, so did I created indexes correct way?

This table currently has `42.000 rows` and `20mb total size`, hosted on `AWS db.t3.small` RDS server (2 vCPUs, 2 GiB of memory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution:

```
FULLTEXT(codfabrica, codoriginal, aplicacao)
```

and

```
MATCH(codfabrica, codoriginal, aplicacao)
    AGAINST("various possible values" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

The reason for performance problems:  `OR` prevents the use of any indexes.

If you would like to discuss further, please provide some sample data for each of the columns.  (`FULLTEXT` has some limitations that you might run into.)